# R dplyr long dataframe factor level summarisation to provide counts, group totals and percentages in one table

Tags: r, dplyr, long-integer, summarize, factors

This question is about prepping data for ggplot

I have a long dataframe of survey questions and option responses (the real one is 76,931 rows) of the form:

```
df <- data.frame( 
Question = c( "Qone", "Qone", "Qone", "Qtwo", "Qtwo", "Qthree", "Qthree"),
Response = as.factor( c( "Opt1", "Opt2","Opt1","Opt1","Opt2","Opt1","Opt2"))
)
```

and I want to create a summary table of the form

| Question | Response | Count | Total_of_Q | Percent_C_of_Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Qone | Opt1 | 2 | 3 | 66.6 |
| Qone | Opt2 | 1 | 3 | 33.3 |
| Qtwo | Opt1 | 1 | 2 | 50 |
| Qtwo | Opt2 | 1 | 2 | 50 |
| Qthree | Opt1 | 1 | 2 | 50 |
| Qthree | Opt2 | 1 | 2 | 50 |

using

```
library(tidyverse)
```

If I write

```
df %>%
   group_by(Question) %>%
   summarise(Total_of_Q = n()) -> totals
totals
```

Totals is

| Question | Total_of_Q |
| --- | --- |
| Qone | 3 |
| Qtwo | 2 |
| Qthree | 2 |

and if I write

```
df %>% 
    group_by(Question) %>%
    count(Response) -> Count
```

Count is

| Question | Response | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Qone | Opt1 | 2 |
| Qone | Opt2 | 1 |
| Qtwo | Opt1 | 1 |
| Qtwo | Opt2 | 1 |
| Qthree | Opt1 | 1 |
| Qthree | Opt2 | 1 |

But at this point I have two data frames that are pretty hard to bind together (because of different row lengths) and I can't help thinking there must be better ways to generate the whole table all at once.

Any hints or suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: When creating a data.frame, use `=`, not `<-`.

Comment: `df %>% count(Question, Response, name = "Count") %>% group_by(Question) %>% mutate(total = sum(Count), pct = Count / sum(Count)) %>% ungroup()`

Comment: In the 1st posted table, why is the second value of `Total_of_Q` a 1?

Comment: @Jon Spring thanks for that. Could you propose it as an answer so I can accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  # shortcut for group_by(Question, Response) %>% summarize(Count = n())` 
  count(Question, Response, name = "Count") %>%   # 1: get detailed counts
  group_by(Question) %>% 
  mutate(total = sum(Count),                      # 2: get counts by queston
         pct = Count / total) %>%                 # 1 divided by 2
  ungroup()
```